# How to attach a Redshift cluster to a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cli, amazon-vpc

Is there any way to attach an existing Redshift cluster to an existing VPC? I would like to do this with AWS CLI. I checked docs but can't see a command related to VPC.

The only thing I see is deploying a cluster inside a VPC when creating the cluster(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/restore-from-cluster-snapshot.html), but I've I already done that

Comment: Where is the Redshift cluster at the moment? Are you saying that you want to _change_ VPCs? The only way for it to _not_ be in a VPC would be if you have an old AWS Account that allows "EC2-Classic" (which means "pre-VPC").

Comment: Right now the cluster is not in any VPC. What about the create-cluster-subnet-group command?

Comment: [Move an Amazon Redshift Cluster From One VPC to Another](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-redshift-cluster-vpcs/)

Comment: [AWS Developer Forums: Move existing Redshift cluster to VPC ...](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=136807)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the VPC of an Amazon Redshift cluster.

You would need to:

- Make a **Snapshot** of the cluster
- **Launch** a new Redshift cluster from the Snapshot, in the desired VPC